# Are there any sophisticated UI widgets that integrate well with Tapestry?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, widget, tapestry

I have been looking for a good Java web framework and found Tapestry, which looks quite nice from an application architecture point of view. Another possibility is ASP and .NET, though I'm reluctant to use them since Java is the programming language most of the company's developer are used to. The reason why ASP is considered is due to its rich set of powerful UI widgets (http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx for instance). Is there anything similar for Tapestry? What I am particularly interested in is tables (sorting, filtering, moving columns, hiding columns, etc.) and possibly others. Alternatively, is there a sophisticated Javascript library which can be easily integrated in Tapestry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my current job we use Tapestry 4, and we chose to use [ExtJS widgets](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) when we need a fancier UI component what Tapestry provides. Their [grid widgets](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-2) are exceptional. ExtJS isn't free for commercial apps, but the abundance of great widgets and documentation makes it *really* easy to work with, and it integrates pretty easily into Tapestry.

Another option would be to use [Java Server Faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces), which has several [high quality component/widget libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces#Ajax-enabled_components_and_frameworks).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking into ExtJS and I think I'll go with it. In the meantime, my preference for Tapestry shifted a bit. I am much more likely to go with the Play! Framework after evaluating a few more framework.

Comment: I've heard about Play! but haven't had a chance to look into it yet. I think you'll be happy with ExtJS. Also - feel free to click that checkmark to the left of my answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

A big library of UI components is a good things. On the other hand there may be no such a set of predefined components that will suite everybody or suite anybody in an ultimate way. The alternative to relying on predefined components (which besides all may require an unexpected time to be learned) is to use a technology with which writing your own components would be an easy pleasure unlike what we see in almost every major Java Web Framework. The approach was implemented in HybridJava which in fact pushed it to the limits with zero predefined components. Yet it may be the most powerful for a task like you've describe.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the first line of the descriptions already puts me off: "...based server-side component-oriented MVC technology for programming...". I found the behaviour of Tapestry kind of awkward and much rather have a framework that works like Django or Play!, request-based that is.

Answer (score 0):

Tapestry already offers a powerful [Grid](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) component.
This component covers all the features you are looking for.
Have a look at [jumpstart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/) to see how to sort,move columns, and hiding columns.

if you prefer the jQuery way perhaps you will have to check "Tapestry5-jquery" that proposes some components that make it possible to use jQuery plugins. The demo site only show the default grid component because it's implementation is still the best one.